# Sitecore ECM Details Report

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms, sitecore-ecm

I am using `Sitecore 6.5 ECM` for my email campaign.

There are quite a number of bugs.. but somehow I managed to overcome them.

Now, ECM is working decently and it has the `Engagement plan` to view how many `percentage` is `Sent`, `Message Opened`, `Message Unopened` and so forth..

But my clients want a details report.. like  `Sent`, `Recipients`, `Opened`, `Clicked` for  every email sent.

[image]

So, I am wondering which method should I pursue to get the following report.

Should I use `EmailCampaign dll APIs` to get them or should I query directly from `database`?

I already took a look at the database. and The table names aren't easy to find out.

Has anyone done this before? Can I have some snippets to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

William - You are correct in that detailed reports like you want from ECM have not yet been done and are not available out of the box.  I know that something like this will be available at some point, but I don' know when and for now, this is how you can go about things because I'm doing this exact thing right now for a client.

Basically it's something that is being done via a straight SQL call.  There is an api in a EngagementAutomation dll.. but from my experience, the method signatures take objects that it's more of a pain to try to create than to just build the SQL calls myself.  Rather than post up my code which is extensive.. I'll just tell you where the data is and how you can go about getting it.  There is a SQL API provided for analytics, but I found it to be more confusing to try to create than to just use old school .net and sql commands myself.

My approach has been to create classes that get back information given something like the GUID for the Engagement plan or the GUID for the Message itself.  There are a couple of tables in the analytics database that track this data.  One is the Automation and AutomationStates which tracks Engagement Plans and the specific emails that are sent (each email sent has an entry in the AutomationStates table which links to the Automation (which is the engagement plan).  The AutomationStates table is pretty key and will show the actual username of the Sitecore user that was sent the email.

Tracking things (clicks and that sort of thing) is a little tricking.  Everything is done and tracked in the Pages table and the PageEvent table.  It tracks opening and clicks.  Opening is tracked via a RegisterEmailOpened url and clicks will have to be tracked in the UrlText field which has the Querystring included and you can parse that column for EC_AS= which points to the AutomationStateID GUID.

There's much more to this, but this should get you started and let you see how to get started on this.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your suggestion. I am a little busy for this report. I will do it probably next week. Thanks for your Answer. :)

Comment: Hi divamatrix, I got the partial working idea. I posted it as another answer and would like to check with u whether they r correct.

Answer (score 1):

I got some results..

just want to check with you whether they are correct?

I will get the `CampaignID` for the respective ECMs from `Campaigns` table.

Then I will get `AutomationID` for that `CampaignID` from `Automation` table..

After that, I will get the respective row from `AutomationStates` table by using the `AutomationID` that I got from `Automation` table.

The number of `Rows` that I get for each `AutomationID` is the number of emails that `ECM` sent.

And if the `VisitorID` is `NULL` that recipient hasn't opened the email.

If there is a value in `VisitorID`, that email can be counted as `Opened`.

For `Click through`, I thought I could use the `StateID` and `StateName` from `AutomationStates` table as I saw some old data of the `StateName` has value called `Unproductive Visitors`

But when I click through my newly sent `ECM`, that field doesn't change anything.

So, I am wondering whether I should user `Visits` table or `Pages` and `PagesEvents` table for `Click through`.

Please advise.

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: The CampaignID refers to the Campaign.. NOT the Engagement plan.  The campaign is much more focused on the marketing aspects and really nothing to do with reporting.  It's useful for the executive summary.. but not for other reporting purposes.  What you really want is the AutomationID which is the Engagement Plan ID and is in the Automations Table.  The ID for the actual ECM Message itself is in the Data field in the Automations Table.

Comment: The number of rows you get for the automationid is the number of emaisl sent for that engagement plan (it's technically possible to have multiple emails configured to use the same engagement plan.. although out of the box, it doesn't do that).  The State refers to the Engagement Plan state .. which is where you would find out if a user has opened the email or clicked links, etc. VisitorID is much more centered around analytics and while it might be useful, it also can be misleading since the foreign/primary key relationships in the analytics database are very complex.

Comment: Click throughs are really tricky since it will record the click throughs as Pages in the Page table, but you have to parse one of the fields in the table to find page entries specific to the ECM message.  Here's a sample SQL statement I used for getting click throughs for each user that was sent an email:  This will show you a bit of how the structure works when passed the automation state ID for each recipient:  SELECT Distinct(ItemId) FROM Pages WHERE Url NOT LIKE '%RegisterEmailOpened%' AND UrlText like '%ec_as%' + @automationstateid + '%'